# CSV file wont stay open in python

Tags: python-3.x, import-csv

Using python 3. In the code below, the 2nd loop will not print, not sure why.

Ignore what I am trying to do, main point is that the file is not accessible beyond the first loop...

any ideas? Thanks!!

```
Import csv
f = open('table.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

# Convert data entries to integers
for row in csv_f:
    if row[0]!="A": row[1:len(row)]=list(map(int,row[1:len(row)]))
    print(row)

# Print table again
for row in csv_f:
    print(row)
```

Comment: This a python feature to prevent you from keeping filepointers open without close. Considered reading your csv to memoryas in https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader?

Comment: @Evgeny not true. It happens because `csv_f` is an iterator that is exhausted after you iterate through it one time. You can keep the handle open for as long as you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do is access data from `csv_f` which is iterator - meaning it can be passed fully only once, then you must generate it again.

You can either make it list:

```
csv_f = list(csv.reader(f))
```

or load the file again, before second loop.

In the meantime I would propose to change your code slightly:

```
with open('table.csv') as f:
    csv_f = list(csv.reader(f))

    # Convert data entries to integers
    for row in csv_f:
        if row[0]!="A": 
            row[1:len(row)]=list(map(int,row[1:len(row)]))
        print(row)

    # Print table again
    for row in csv_f:
        print(row)
```

That way the file won't stay open outside of `with open() as f` statement - much better practice than using simple `open()`